# Bar chart matlab by scalar vectors

Tags: matlab, charts, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar chart where my x axis shows only one data point, year of 2006, but for 3 different data related to 2006. I am doing the following, but I receive the 
error of "X must be same length as Y."

Here is my code and I highly appreciate your help:

```
X=[2006] %year

   % Create data for childhood disease cases

   measles = [38556];

   mumps = [20178];

   chickenPox = [37140];


   % Create a vertical bar chart using the bar function

   figure;

   bar(X, [measles' mumps' chickenPox'],'group');


   % Set the axis limits

   %axis([0 13 0 40000]);


   % Add title and axis labels

   title('Childhood diseases by month');

   xlabel('Month');

   ylabel('Cases (in thousands)');


   % Add a legend

   legend('Measles', 'Mumps', 'Chicken pox');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `X` is only one element and you are using three different `Y` values.

I think this problem requires you to take a step back a bit. Why are you plotting all three against the same X value? If this worked as you specified, all three would be on top of each other.

Would it not be more informative to the viewer if the X-axis labeled each bar as measles, mumps or chickenPox?

Try:

```
bar([measles' mumps' chickenPox']);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'Measles','Mumps','Chicken Pox'});
```

Edit:

I see what you're after. You're almost correct. The problem is that since you only have one column of data, matlab assumes you DON'T want to create a group but just plot those 3 values against unique X values. So we need to trick it slightly by creating another data point.

```
% //Create two columns, one of them zeros
data = [[measles;mumps;chickenPox],[0;0;0]];
bar([X,X+1],data'); % //The 2007 entry will not be visible
```

This will create a group at 2006 and the 2007 entry will be zeros so you won't see it. You can then set your axes and such to be the same as the other charts.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment. Actually, I have other cases that cover a range of years, e.g.
 
   X=[2006,2007]
 
   measles = [38556, 1235];
   mumps = [20178, 2343];
   chickenPox = [37140,2345];
 
and I want all diagrams to be consistent! The above code does work when I have 2 or more years, but shows the "X must be same length as Y" error in case of only 1 year!